# Simple exception handling

Tags: c#, exception

Hey so if I have this exception:

```cs
try
{
    List<string> inputFileLines = GetInputFileFormatted(mailFile);
}
catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("File not found");
}
```

How do I access inputFileLines outside of the try statement it it works?

Comment: Simple, you have to declare it outside.

Comment: What do you plan on doing with `inputFileLines` if its null?

Comment: thats the thing, i want the program just to stop if its null? But how do i do this

Comment: Why do you want to access `inputFileLines` outside `try` block? Why don't write next line of code below `List<string> inputFileLines = ...`?

Comment: Declare it as `List<string> inputFileLines = null;` before the `try {`

Comment: i updated the question, any help is grealty appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<string> inputFileLines = null;
try
{
    inputFileLines = GetInputFileFormatted(mailFile);
}
catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("File not found");
}
//now you can access inputFileLines outside of 'try' and check if it is null or not.
```

Comment: I have a long stretch of code after this exception block, how do i exit the program without getting an error afterwards

Answer (score 0):

> How do I access inputFileLines outside of the try statement it it works?

Your current scope is within the `try` block (block scope) and only accessible in it...

```
try
{
    List<string> inputFileLines = GetInputFileFormatted(mailFile);
}
catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("File not found");
}
```

If you want to access it outside the `try` you need to move the scope of that outside (method scope) as already mentioned.

```
 List<string> inputFileLines = null;
 try
    {
        inputFileLines = GetInputFileFormatted(mailFile);
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("File not found");
    }
```

**Edit per comment** (from the question I had asked you)

> What do you plan on doing with inputFileLines if its null?

Your response was:

> thats the thing, i want the program just to stop if its null? But how
>   do i do this

The reason I asked this is because you *don't* need to declare it outside if you want to exit the application. Look up [Application.Exit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.exit?view=netframework-4.8) method, which informs all message pumps that they must terminate, and then closes all application windows after the messages have been processed.

```
try
{
    List<string> inputFileLines = GetInputFileFormatted(mailFile);
    if(inputFileLines == null)
       System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit();
}
catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("File not found");
    System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit();
}
```

Now if that list is null or an exception is thrown, it will exit the application.

IMHO check into [scope of variables](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scope-of-variables-in-c-sharp/) to get a better understanding of how they are accessible.

**References:**

Application.Exit Method https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.exit?view=netframework-4.8